# Create regular expression from natural language

Tags: java, regex

I would like to know where its possible to create regular expression from natural language in Java. To explain this, let me give a use case.

Support I want to check whether the following string is in correct format or not.

```
"aaaa-bbbb-cccc"
```

The business definition of a valid string in this case is as follows:

```
4 letters, then hyphen, then 4 letters, then hyphen, then 4 letters.
```

The usual way to implement this is to get the requirements from business and write the regex accordingly. But I am curious to know whether any libraries are available to create regex from natural language. So that we can ask business to provide the formats in a way that they can also understand.

Comment: you may want to use a compiler compiler like ANTLR, YACC etc.  This will give you more flexibility.

Comment: You could implement a relatively simple DSL via a builder pattern

Comment: In general it is a very, very hard problem to provide a 'natural language' way of writing any strict specification. People have written PhD theses on these subjects.

Comment: Actually, no its not. There is no order to natural language. Even if something had a minor repeatability its almost impossible to get a useable machine created regex. And regex constructs themselves are limited, and usually are the basis for complex non-regex algorithms.

Comment: If you let business people write these you're not going to get them to conform to some strict syntax, even if that syntax is much simpler than regex and more like natural language. A valid definition that specifies the same thing as your example could be "It should be three groups of four letters separated by dashes"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at business rules engines available for Java: [Drools](http://www.drools.org), [Jess](http://jessrules.com), [EasyRules](http://www.easyrules.org/). In business rules engine you can define requirements (rules) you get from business and then check incoming data (facts) against them.

Comment: That may work in the case described but it's not a regex. Can OP clarify the need of regex?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [simply-regex](https://itsallbinary.com/project-simply-regex/simply-regex-quick-start/) library.

This is how you will be able to create regex within your code which will be self explanatory. Instead of having regex variable with typed string, you can have it built one time with readable code as per your requirements. Also easy to change later.

```
String builtRegex = SimpleRegex.regex().startingWith().exactString("abc")
                                   .then().oneOfTheCharacters('d', 'e', 'f')
                                   .build(); 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(builtRegex); 
boolean isMatch = pattern.matcher(testString).matches();
```